# ament_cmake vs ament_python?

Tags: ros, ros2, ament

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just started learning ros2 and I want to create a new package, and I noticed that it is possible to create a package with 2 different build types, ament_cmake and ament_python. However, I didn't find any explanation about the difference between both, what are the advantages and disadvantages of each one? Is one meant for c++ and the other for python?

I am following this tutorial: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Creating-A-ROS2-Package/#createpkg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342118/ament_cmake-vs-ament_python?/) by [rezenders](https://answers.ros.org/users/37912/rezenders/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2020-01-20

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is one meant for c++ and the other for python?

Yes this is the main reason.

`ament_cmake` can be used for CMake package (usually C and C++), and provide some CMake magic to make things less verbose and more convenient to use with the ROS tools. It tells the build tool to build the package using a cmake workflow: cmake -> make -> make install.
Some examples of packages available [here](https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree/e28168cb632e8622f575f0903b5a419593138a7a/rclcpp)

`ament_python` it is used for pure python packages and tells the build tools to use a setuptools workflow: python setup.py -> python setup.py install.
Some examples of packages available [here](https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree/e28168cb632e8622f575f0903b5a419593138a7a/rclpy)

> I didn't find any explanation about the difference between both

It looks like a good area of [improvement for the tutorial](https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation), as it should likely introduce these types in the introduction.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5